# Phalcon Devtools error: generate controllers, models and scaffold not working (404 not found page)

Tags: php, mysql, web, xampp, phalcon

(this text is automatically translated from Spanish to English.)

Hello, I would like to ask about this error that Phalcon devtools shows when generating a controller, model or scaffold:

[image]

[image]

my configurations are as follows (config,php)

[image]

Details:

-System versions: Phalcon Devtools 4.1.0

-Phalcon Framework version: Phalcon 4.1.0

-PHP Version: PHP Version 7.4.16

-Operating System: Windows 10

-Server: Apache and MySQL

Comment: Please post the text of the error -- the screenshot should only be included if there is additional context that is only obtainable via that image.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not related to phalcon-devtools.
You should configure you webserver vhost to handle this requests.
For example in nginx:

```
server {
    ...
    # Here setting to handle requests on index.php
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?_url=$uri&$args;
    }
    
    # Here setting to handle requests on webtools.php
    location /webtools {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /webtools.php?_url=$uri&$args;
    }
    ...
}
```